# Is it possible that two or more websites may have same Alexa traffic rank?

Tags: ranking, alexa

Is it possible for two or more websites to have same Alexa traffic rank?

I am developing a tools that depend on the Alexa rank, but I'm finding multiple domains with same Alexa rank.

Comment: Maybe, but need so many real [Alexa Hits](http://www.socialmediacore.com/product/buy-alexa-traffic/)

Comment: This question had originally said "URLs" rather than "websites."   Alexa ranks sites, so every URL on one site will have the same ranking.     I believe this question is actually asking about domains, not URLs, so I have edited it to reflect that.

Answer (score 2):

I think you just answered your own question.

Maybe there are domains that have exactly the same score so rank the same. A bit like two second placers and no third.

Answer (score 2):

Any Alexa rank above 100000 is pretty unreliable and prone to change. The Website never shows any two websites as having the same Alexa rank whenever I checked! Can you tell us which URLs you found to be having the same Alexa rank?

Basically, Websites with Alexa rank above 100000 are just starting out or are not that popular. So, you should really consider your application for those below 100,000.